# Typescript conditionally required parameters

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that takes in some parameters, and they should be optional, but if they are present, then I want other parameters to be required.

Here's a very silly example:

```js
type PersonInfo = {
  name: string; 
  age: number; 
  pets?: boolean; 
  petNames?: string[]; 
}
const recordPersonInfo = (options: PersonInfo) => {
  database.save(options); 
}
```

So the `pets` property can be omitted, but if it is `true` then I want `petNames` to be required. How can I tell Typescript to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a union type: the `pets` property is a discriminant, so if you write `if(options.pets)` then inside the `if` block, `options` will be narrowed to definitely have the `petNames` property.

```
type PersonInfo = {
  name: string; 
  age: number;
} & ({
  pets?: false;
} | {
  pets: true; 
  petNames: string[]; 
})

const recordPersonInfo = (options: PersonInfo) => {
  database.save(options); 
}
```

Comment: I thought I could use a union to do this, but I just needed someone to show me how. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Making use of function overloading, you can do something like this:

```js
type PersonInfoWithPets = PersonInfo & { pets: true; petNames: string[] };
type PersonInfoWithoutPets = PersonInfo & { pets?: false; petNames?: undefined };


function recordPersonInfo(options: PersonInfoWithPets): void;
function recordPersonInfo(options: PersonInfoWithoutPets): void;
function recordPersonInfo(options: PersonInfo): void {

}

recordPersonInfo({
    name: 'name',
    age: 0,
});
recordPersonInfo({
    name: 'name',
    age: 0,
    pets: false,
});
recordPersonInfo({
    name: 'name',
    age: 0,
    pets: true,
    petNames: [],
});
// This errors because `pets` but no `petNames`
recordPersonInfo({
    name: 'name',
    age: 0,
    pets: true,
});
// This errors because `petNames` but no `pets`
recordPersonInfo({
    name: 'name',
    age: 0,
    petNames: ['hi'],
});
// NOTE: This also errors because `pets` is a boolean here, not strictly true/false
recordPersonInfo(null! as PersonInfo);
```

So honestly, TypeScript doesn't provide a perfect solution for this. In this specific case, you could say "the presence (and emptiness) of `petNames` should replace the need for the `pets` field" of course. And in this case we got away with two overloads, but more complex situations can lead to the need for more overloads.

Of course, you could just properly document the function, and throw an error should a wrong input still be given.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've never used overloads, but I need to look into them more.